# Mockito Multipart file argument matcher

Tags: mockito, integration-testing, void

I am trying to have an integration test that throwns an exception for a void method to simulate a downed service. The method has a string param and a multipart file as a param and it does not seem to be working even though an exception is thrown for a void method with two string parameters.

Working integration test:

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("500 response -- downed case mgmt microservice")
    public void downedCaseMgmt() throws Exception {
        BDDMockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("mocking an error")).when(reportEventService).reportDocUpload(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class), ArgumentMatchers.anyString());

        //Rest assured portion
        given().
                multiPart("file", xlsxGoodFile).
                params(paramsMap).
        when().
                post("").
        then().
                statusCode(500);
    }
```

Non-working integration test:

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("500 response -- downed object storage")
    public void downedObjectStorage() throws Exception {
        BDDMockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("mocking an error")).when(objectStorageService).saveFileToObjectStorage(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(File.class));

        //Rest assured portion
        given().
                multiPart("file", xlsxGoodFile).
                params(paramsMap).
        when().
                post("").
        then().
                statusCode(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the function saveFileToObjectStorage had a null value because of the mockbean on objectStorageService and the fact that I was mocking a return. Error on my part and I resolved it with the following code:

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("500 response -- downed db")
    public void downedDb() throws Exception {
        BDDMockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("mocking an error")).when(excelDataRepository).
                save(ArgumentMatchers.any());

        //Rest assured portion
        given().
                multiPart("file", xlsxGoodFile).
                params(paramsMap).
        when().
                post("").
        then().
                statusCode(500);
    }
```

NOTE: the any() of ArgumentMatchers